# Allow users to edit text within a C# asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, user-input

I would like to allow users to edit the text within my C# asp.net application. For example, a user should be able to edit the message on the home page ('welcome on my site....'). The problem with this, is the markup of such a text. I do know how to allow a user to edit text, but it would be nice if it was possible to add things like white lines, headers and paragraphs. It is important that the users aren't bothered with HTML code. They should only have to type some text and press the save button.

My question is: How can I accomplish this? Are are any good text-to-html plugins (I did not find one), or is there a better way to do this?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you can use 
[CKEditor](http://www.CKEditor.com)

Perfect Editor i seen ever.

Comment: @Attiej Don't forget about sanitization if you allow people to use an HTML editor.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, the only person that will be able to use the editor, is the owner of the site. But it is something I have to keep in mind!